# Tribes Vengeance Save Location?

Tags: tribes-vengeance

Where are the save game files for Tribes Vengeance when installed on Windows 10? After installing with the [Tribes Revengeance](http://tribesrevengeance.com/) package and playing a while I found an empty "\Program Files (x86)\VUGames\Tribes Vengeance\Content\Saves" folder. Yet it must have been saving somewhere as quick save and load worked in game.

Searches of AppData and ProgramData haven't turned up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out saves end up in the VirtualStore:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\VUGames\Tribes Vengeance\Content\Saves
```